# jQuery - Apply method to multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the same method on a number of declared variables.

E.g. say i have:

```
var searchBtn = $('#search');
var signInBtn = $('#signin');

signInBtn.removeClass('active');
searchBtn.removeClass('active');
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$(signInBtn, searchBtn).removeClass('active');
```

But I can't, `searchBtn` is interpreted as scope in this context (I think).

My question is, how can I combine defined objects and run the same method on them?

Note: Just to clarify, I'm not talking about targeting elements using ID, classes, etc, I'm talking about objects that have been defined as variables.

Comment: you can also do this: `$('.active').removeClass('active');`.

Comment: That's another approach, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to combine two sets of jquery objects:

```
var searchBtn = $('#search');
var signInBtn = $('#signin');

signInBtn.add(searchBtn).removeClass('active');
```

If you have multiple objects, you can chain the `add()`s or put the objects in an array and [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) them together (`add()` doesn't support multiple arguments):

```
[signInBtn,searchBtn,anotherButton].reduce(function(a,b){return a.add(b);})
    .removeClass('active');
```

**Sample Snippet**

```js
$('#deactivate').click(function() {

  var searchBtn = $('#search');
  var signInBtn = $('#signin');
  var exitBtn = $('#exit');

  [searchBtn, signInBtn, exitBtn].reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.add(b);
    })
    .removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search" class="active">Search</button>
<button id="signin" class="active">Sign In</button>
<button id="exit" class="active">Exit</button>

<button id="deactivate">Deactivate</button>
```

Comment: Okay this is good, much closer to what I want. What if there are 4 or 5 objects, just keep using a `.add?` Or can I combine them all into one `.add?`

Answer (score 0):

What about an `array`? Put your objects in an array and loop it with `each()`

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the docs, `jQuery()` can take an array of DOM elements and turn them into a collection, so if you don't mind the extra overhead you could just do:

```
$([signInBtn[0], searchBtn[0]]).removeClass('active');
```

This is pretty redundant since it gets the DOM nodes from your jQuery objects just to turn them back into jQuery objects, but I guess it saves you having to loop through them and `add()` them to an empty collection.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#search,#signin').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `add()` to add elements to an already existing jQuery context:

```
searchBtn.add(signInBtn).removeClass('active');
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

Comment: I know I can target multiple elements this way, my question is about targeting defined variables, i.e. objects.