# jquery apply listener to set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out if there is a solution to this simple but complex task.

Let's say we have this variables:

```
var dom1 = $('.selector1');
var dom2 = $('.selector2');
```

Now I want to apply for example a listener to dom1 and dom2. Is there a different, direct and more reliable solution than apply one by one the function?

```
dom1.click(function(){
    //a lot of stuff
}
dom2.click(function(){
    //the same lot of stuff
}
//or
$([dom1,dom2]).each(function(){
    this.click(function(){
        //the same lot of stuff
    });
}
```

I know this is not a working solution, but I'm searching something like this:

```
//NOT WORKING, NON-SENSE, I KNOW
$([dom1,dom2]).click(function(){
    //the same lot of stuff
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: that's it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294143/jquery-apply-method-to-multiple-objects, i didn't catch it early, thank you @Rhumborl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either select both sets elements using a comma separated selector:

```
$('.selector1, .selector2').click(fn);
```

Alternatively, you can use `add()` to join together two variables which contain jQuery objects:

```
dom1.add(dom2).click(fn);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`jQuery.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add) which adds the element to the current collection.

```
dom1.add(dom2).click(function(){
    // your code goes here
});
```

Else, you can use selectors separated by a comma.